# Need to use logical operation in an MS Acess query field

Tags: microsoft-access, query

Let's say I have a table in MS Access.  It has a text field, "size".  There are only a few values size can take: "tiny", "small", "medium", "large", "jumbo".  I want to create a query with a field that will calculate a number based on the table's size field.  Where size is "tiny" the new field should be 1, "small" 2, "medium" 3, etc.  I guess I need to make use of logical operations to do this but, after reviewing what material I can find on them, I still don't know how.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a field and set its Data type to Calculated. Enter the following on the EXpression builder window:

```
IIf([Size]="tiny","1",IIf([Size]="small","2",IIf([Size]="medium","3",IIf([Size]="large","4","5"))))
```

[image]

When adding new data, the calculated table will derived its values based on the selected/entered size as seen below. Change the field name `[Size]` to the name you have given it on your table.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  But "IIf"???  Who thought that up???  Thanks again.